# How to click on the Read the guide button using Selenium after logged in through Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I need a script which logs me in to github and presses a Read the guide button. I've got it to log in but after it's done it does not work any more. Please help.

```
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://github.com/session')

login_area = browser.find_element_by_name('login')
login_area.send_keys('maximmashkov')

login_area = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
login_area.send_keys('12345')

submit_button = browser.find_element_by_name('commit')
submit_button.click()
```

Comment: to put a little time.sleep() delay , then try to get whatever element you have to click.

Answer (score 1):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Read the guide** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Read the guide"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-primary[href='https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/' and text()='Read the guide']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your script fails to wait for the "Read the guide" button to appear, consider using [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) so Selenium could wait for a defined period of time for the element to appear in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#initialize your browser here

login_area = browser.find_element_by_name('login')
login_area.send_keys('maximmashkov')

login_area = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
login_area.send_keys('12345')

submit_button = browser.find_element_by_name('commit')
submit_button.click()

submit_button = browser.find_element_by_name('commit')
submit_button.click()

read_the_guide = element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Read the guide")))
read_the_guide.click()

browser.quit()
```

More information:

- [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)
- [How to wait for elements in Python Selenium WebDriver](http://allselenium.info/wait-for-elements-python-selenium-webdriver/)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was posted in the question and moved here:

You only have to put a little time.sleep() delay. One second is enough